# Hyperlink to certain text in excel page?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet, hyperlink

I'm trying to create hyperlinks to certain points in a large data sheet. Each are separated by a block of text identifying what is there. I know I could create the hyperlink to certain cells in the sheet however the data is constantly changing so trying to jump to A500 might work one day but after some data is moved or deleted the text I'm trying to jump to will move too. I want to be able to jump to a certain text using hyperlink is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create named ranges and take care not to delete them. Then create a hyperlink using the named range as the target. Data can be inserted or removed, as long as the cell(s) with range names are not removed.

Comment: I've never created named ranges can you explain how to do it or do you have a link to a video that explains in more detail?

Comment: Nevermind I got it thank you so much

Comment: I'm actually having problems with that, I hyperlink to the named range and now I can't insert a row it tells me that the data will go over the edge.

Comment: That's weird. Please start a new question and post a link to it in the comment.